# iOS -- AVAudioSession smallest possible file

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am attempting to sample audio with the following settings:

No matter how small I get my AVSampleRateKey to be, the filesize for the audio does not go below 83kb. I need it to be in the range of 20kb to 50kb.

What settings should I be using instead? (This is for a 10second file).

```
recordSetting = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4096.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:8],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:0], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                              [NSData data], AVChannelLayoutKey, nil];

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];


recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
[recorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];

[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 10];
[recorder record];
```

Comment: I don't see the key AVEncoderBitRateKey. If you add that and set it to 256, aka 8-bit, does it help? I couldn't find the default bit rate size in the Apple docs.

Comment: I added that in but it didn't help.

Comment: btw I see you are doing [recorder recordForDuration..] and then [recorder record]. [.. recordForDuration] starts recording. [.. record] starts recording and records until you call [recorder stop];. Just fyi.